# Will Rufus allow me to UPGRADE to windows 11 pro with a local account, or does a local account require a clean install?

Tags: installation, windows-11, rufus

My laptop has been bugging me to upgrade to windows 11, and I know that currently, the windows update version of the upgrade forces you to take on a microsoft account.  I like my local account, and not being part of the microsoft hive.  I am not averse to doing a clean install, but I'd rather not have to reinstall all my software.

I ran latest version of Rufus and made a windows 11 pro installation thumb drive.  I indicated that it was to install with a local account, and I provided the name.  What I am not clear on, is whether that local account gets created only for clean installs, or if it works for upgrading as well (upgrading with media).  I have my c-drive cloned, so I can get back to where I was if the installation tries to absorb me into the Microsoft hive, but I'd rather know ahead of time that a clean install is necessary.

Comment: If your current system is Windows 11 eligible, and you already have a local account, then just upgrade to Windows 11 through Windows Update.  Using a Rufus ISO, to acomplish the upgrade, seems uncessary in the case you describe

Comment: Currently, the upgrade through windows update tries to force you into a microsoft account, and does not let you use your current local account  You can do an upgrade with disk media as an alternative to using windows update.

Comment: Since you haven’t performed the upgrade, how do you know, Windows after the upgrade will force you to link a Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 3):

The option is not relevant because Windows upgrades do nothing regarding accounts in the first place – you'll continue to have exactly the same files, registry, and accounts as before. That's what makes it an "upgrade" rather than a "reinstall".